# AppendBlockAsync - Create Blob if not exists

Tags: .net, azure, azure-storage

We have multiple parallel workers in a distributed environment that uses [AppendBlockAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudappendblob.appendblockasync?view=azure-dotnet-legacy) to append data to a blob. Every hour a new blob should be created and all the workers will start appending to the new blob in parallel.

The problem is when and where to create the blob. I don't see a valid AccessCondition that I can pass to AppendBlockAsync such that if a blob doesn't exist, it creates one and appends to it.

Today, we are catching the exception to AppendBlockAsync and based on the exception type we create blob if it doesn't exist. But it doesn't seem right to do it from client(workers). The Server(Azure Storage Account) should have a way to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle it in client.

For example, use the `.Exists()` method to check if the file exists or not. If it does not exist, just create the file.

The sample code looks like below:

```
        //your other code
        var client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = client.GetContainerReference("xxx");

        var blobclient = container.GetAppendBlobReference("xx");
        if (!blobclient.Exists())
        {
            try
            {
                blobclient.CreateOrReplace(AccessCondition.GenerateIfNotExistsCondition(), null, null);
            }
            catch (StorageException) 
            { }

        }
        
        await blobclient.AppendBlockAsync(xxx);
    
        //other code.
```